# What is the difference in angularJS between ui.router and ui.state?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am working on getting an angularJS SPA setup with multiple views using [angular ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

As I look aroun dthe web at tutorials and how-to's, I see a mixed bag of dependencies. The ui-router github page has examples that use `ui.router` as the module dependency, while other articles such as Ben Schwartz [tutorial](http://txt.fliglio.com/2013/05/angularjs-state-management-with-ui-router/) uses `ui.state`.

What is the difference? Is one deprecated? Is `ui.state` a subset of `ui.router`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In summary, `ui.state` was for v0.0.1, while `ui.router` is for v0.2.0 (the current version).

`ui.state` was the necessary module for users to inject as a dependency in v0.0.1 of ui-router. See the [README](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/9ea2bb4c2b40009be76edd12c073c45db3db322e/README.md) at that release, as well as the relevant snippet from [angular-ui-router.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/9ea2bb4c2b40009be76edd12c073c45db3db322e/release/angular-ui-router.js) (lines 45-48):

```
angular.module('ui.util', ['ng']);
angular.module('ui.router', ['ui.util']);
angular.module('ui.state', ['ui.router', 'ui.util']);
angular.module('ui.compat', ['ui.state']);
```

The [README](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/818b0d69d2063064ca6d2e3b05252200439862d3/README.md) at v0.2.0 states under Quick Start: `Set ui.router as a dependency in your module. Note: Use ui.state if using v0.0.1.`

This is of course corroborated by [angular-ui-router.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/release/angular-ui-router.js) at v0.2.0, lines 79-83, showing the corresponding module dependency structure at that point:

```
angular.module('ui.router.util', ['ng']);
angular.module('ui.router.router', ['ui.router.util']);
angular.module('ui.router.state', ['ui.router.router', 'ui.router.util']);
angular.module('ui.router', ['ui.router.state']);
angular.module('ui.router.compat', ['ui.router']);
```

Comment: Thank you Sarah, that certainly clears it up for me. I appreciate you taking the time to help me out!