# Hello World in UI-Router runs in fiddle but not in local drive--why?

Tags: angularjs

[The fiddle works](http://fiddle.jshell.net/gogirl/sqQKy/):The same code on the local drive does not render the template "Hello World". I have tried downloading the release, pasting the code instead of the script tag  and the same with the a.js file. Neither helped and i dont think ui router is loading no matter what I do. I am really hoping to move on from fiddles and create real apps. Below snapshots of my latest attempt.

[image: myApp]
[image: a.js]
[image: Result]

[Reference & Credits](http://txt.fliglio.com/2013/05/angularjs-state-management-with-ui-router/)

EDIT (Newbies take note):Ben Schwartz tutorial uses ui.state as does mine. ui.state was for v0.0.1, while ui.router is for v0.2.0 (the current version): [difference between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964629/what-is-the-difference-in-angularjs-between-ui-router-and-ui-state/19965114#19965114)

Answer (score 2):

Due to security restrictions, your browser won't execute the javascript when you access the files via "file://". You need to run a local dev server (like node) and access the files through that. The [angular tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00) has some info on setting up a server.

Comment: Chris thanks for the reply. The browser recognizes ng-directives and data coming from my own controllers. What is so special about ui-router that would make it different? IOW, I can print a hello world using MyController which to me sounds like  javascript accessed via  "file://". I also find it strange tat there is no mention of this in the get started section. It states download the release with no mention of node. Perhaps you can straighten me out further?

Answer (score 0):

"You need to run a local dev server": The no brainer and easiest way I found to transition from fiddles was to download and use WEbstorm. I copied all the files from the sample demo and created a new project that ran on Web Storm's server. I also suggest using the comments in the code as a way to get acquainted with UI Router and skip all outdated tutorials. You will usually need plunkers to display code that require several files as jsfiddle is better for simpler demos. These things may be obvious to most frontend developers but less understood by newcomers who are unfamiliar with the various tools.